# Fuzzy search using mongoose from vue client

Tags: vue.js, mongoose, fuzzy-search, feathersjs

Getting error unknown top level operator $regex

search.vue    `

```
let questDocuments = await conversation
        .find({ query: { $limit: 100, $search: q, skippop: true } })
        .then(response => {`
```

q is the string being passed

service hook

```
before: {
    all: [],
    find: [
      hookBeforeFind,
      search({
        fields: ["label"],
        deep: true
      })      
    ],
```

Model

```
const conversation = new Schema(
    {
      label: { type: String, required: true },
      nodeId: { type: String, required: true },
      details: { type: String },
      url: { type: String },
      creator: { type: String },
      handle: { type: String },
      date: { type: String },
```

From search bar add expression to search. E.g "the"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add $regex to the [whitelist option](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-mongoose/#serviceoptions) of the Mongoose service:

```
app.use('/messages', service({
  Model,
  whitelist: [ '$regex' ]
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
// regex to find records that start with letter any name , example "e"
  Model.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        field_name: {
          $regex: "^" + searchName,
          $options: "i"
        }
      }
    }]).exec(function(err, result) {
    if (err) { // handle here }
    if (result) { // do something }
    }
```